# mysql service doesent work on windows 7

Tags: mysql, wamp

I am trying to start my sql service on windows

In the command prompt i continuously have this error message:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

In the sql log file I got the following

```
2015-08-31 00:53:41 5348 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-31 00:53:41 5348 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-31 00:53:41 5348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-31 00:53:41 5348 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-08-31 00:53:41 5348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-31 00:53:41 5348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-31 00:53:41 5348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-31 00:53:41 5348 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-31 00:53:42 5348 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file .\ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
2015-08-31 00:53:42 5348 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file .\ibdata1 size to 12 MB
2015-08-31 00:53:42 5348 [Note] InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
2015-08-31 00:53:42 5348 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create .\ib_logfile101
2015-08-31 00:53:42 5348 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-08-31 00:53:42 5348 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-08-31 00:53:42 5348 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-08-31 00:53:42 5348 [ERROR] Aborting
```

How can this problem be solved ?

Comment: *Cannot create .\ib_logfile101* doesn't describes too much, but as a wild guess, does the MySql service account have write permissions to that location?

Answer (score 1):

**Please make a backup before deleting any files.**

You need to clean your replay logs.
-ib_logfile0
-ib_logfile1
-ibdata1

Refer to the following post that is related.
On windows this file might be in xampp\mysql\data directory.

http://www.debian-tutorials.com/how-to-fix-error-unknownunsupported-storage-engine-innodb

Please take note that this probably means that you have disabled InnoDb. Is this what you really want.

Check you my.inf file. You could turn Innodb support on and off here as you please.

```
[mysqld] 
innodb=OFF 
ignore-builtin-innodb 
skip-innodb
default-storage-engine=myisam 
default-tmp-storage-engine=myisam
```

Comment: nice answer crafter. Good support.

Comment: I am using wamp not xampp. When I open my my.ini file I find just this:                        [mysqld]
port=3306
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE

Comment: @pentanol, so the issue here is that you have InnoDB support disabled somehow and your data/replay log files handing around, MySQL cannot start the database because InnoDb is not supported. So you either delete the files, or enable support for innoDb - your choice.

Comment: You are going off-track, here... I believe that's a misinterpretation: InnoDB is being disabled *only because of* the prior error, which is most likely permissions-related, or potentially low disk space.  InnoDB clearly is enabled because it wouldn't otherwise try to initialize these files.  The only relevant error at the moment is `[ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create .\ib_logfile101`.